# Incorrect inventory when saving a product as an order gets placed

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, inventory, core, bug

I experienced the following behavior in Magento 1.7.0.2:

1. Edit product
2. Go to inventory tab
3. View inventory

In my test inventory on the product was sitting at 9 units.

4. I place an order for the product on the front-end whilst keeping the product edit page open
5. After the order is placed, I click `Save` on the product edit page (while inventory is still at 9)

Now inventory is sitting on 7 (in other words, 2 units deducted) even though only 1 was ordered.

I repeated this by placing the order in a similar fashion in the back-end, and experienced the same behavior.

Is this just me or do your sites behave similarly? If so, how can this be resolved? I haven't found any official bug report.

**Edit:** If you view the product inventory level in a new tab after having just placed the order, it seems like the stock level is correct. However, once you click `Save` on your open tab (whilst editing), the inventory is then reduced by 2 units.

**Edit 2:** I've posted what I think may be the solution to this issue.

- So am I correct in saying that the answer I posted is a solution?
- Can anybody think of any problems this change may have?
- What exactly were the dev team thinking with the `setQtyCorrection` method?

Comment: I would expect it the other way around? If you place an order and then save, the stock is back to 9 instead of 8?

Comment: I was also under the same impression. Could you by chance check this on your staging site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tracked this down into `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php`.

The event `catalog_product_save_after` calls the `saveInventoryData` method which in turn calls the `_prepareItemForSave` method.

Around line 225:

```
$originalQty = $product->getData('stock_data/original_inventory_qty');
if (strlen($originalQty)>0) {
    $item->setQtyCorrection($item->getQty()-$originalQty);
}
```

If you comment out this line:

```
$item->setQtyCorrection($item->getQty()-$originalQty);
```

It seems to correct the problem & stock levels now stay correct when saving a product whilst simultaneously creating / canceling an order on both the front & back-end of the website.